# N-to-N relationship select

Tags: mysql, database

I new to mysql, and got some troubles on select with entities that have n-to-n relationship.
I have the following tables:

```
books(isbn, name, ...)
authors(author_id, fullname)
writtens(author_id, isbn) // primary key (author_id, isbn)
```

**Is there any way to find all pair of authors that both authors written at least two books together?**

For example:

```
BOOKS:
 isbn     name
'isbn1' 'book1'
'isbn2' 'book2'
'isbn3' 'book3'

AUTHORS:
author_id fullname
1         'author1'
2         'author2'
3         'author3'

WRITTENS:
author_id isbn
1         'isbn1'
1         'isbn2'
1         'isbn3'
2         'isbn1'
2         'isbn2'
3         'isbn2'
```

The result may look like:

```
author_id author_id
1           2
```

Because I'm new to mysql, the result format I expected may not correct, you can change the result format.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> find all pair of authors that both authors written at least two books together

```sql
SELECT t1.author_id, t2.author_id
FROM writtens t1
JOIN writtens t2 USING (isbn)
WHERE t1.author_id < t2.author_id
GROUP BY t1.author_id, t2.author_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT isbn) > 1
```

If `(author_id, isbn)` in `writtens` is defined as unique then DISTINCT not needed.

If you need authors names then join 2 copies of `authors` table additionally.

Comment: Just desirable to give aliases for `t1.author_id as written_by, t2.author_id as written_with`

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I think this is incorrect. There is no any info that some author is primary, so we must assume that they're peer. It's not good when Aaron is always "written by" whereas Zachary have no chance...